# Unit Testing angularjs directive with angular-material-design with requirejs throws a "GET" error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, karma-jasmine, angular-material

My app uses requirejs as well as angularjs.
I'm using *text!* in order to load my templates (so as not to use templateURL in my directives). It all works fine - unless one of the directives contains an image in its template.

I'm now trying to setup my tests for new directives with icons in their templates, with no success.
For instance, I have the following directive template:

```
<buttonDirective>
  <md-icon md-svg-src="/android.svg" alt="android "></md-icon>
</buttonDirective>
```

Karma yells at me that "/android.svg" is being called (the known "GET" error: Unexpected request: GET IMAGEFILEPATH).

I've tried to add my image files to the karma config, but this did not solve the issue.

Any way around this besides not using the md-icon? (it works when I change the m d-icon to a simple image, so I guess the issue is that the md-icon directive is using some async call to the svg file and Karma hates that...).

Answer (score 3):

I got around this issue by using `$httpBackend` to mock the request:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

    $httpBackend
        .whenGET('images/ic_forward_24px.svg')
        .respond('');

    $httpBackend
        .whenGET('images/ic_backward_24px.svg')
        .respond('');

    $rootScope.$digest();

}));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can mock the directive entirely:

```
module('app', function ($provide) {
    $provide.factory('mdIconDirective', function () {
      return angular.noop;
    });
});
```